# what's the semantics of Prolog's implementation of negation with non-ground literals

Tags: prolog, negation, first-order-logic

I am familiar with Prolog's implementation of negation as NaF and that even its implementation of NaF is incomplete, esp. floundering with non ground negated literals. My question here is regarding the specific semantics. Suppose you have a clause `p(X) :- q(Y)`. This is the clausal form of *\A x,y(q(y) -> p(x))* which is *\E y q(y) -> \A x p(x)*, and this is indeed the semantics that prolog implements. But now consider if I have `p(X) :- \+ q(Y)`. In FOL this would be expressed as *\E y ~q(y) -> \A x p(x)* ie "if q fails for some y then p holds for every x" but this does not appear to be the semantics that Prolog implements. Rather Prolog will require q to finitely fail for every y before `\+ q(y)` succeeds and p is true for any x. So its semantics appears to be very different, not just incomplete. Am I missing something?

thanks

Comment: You really need to connect the variables shared between `p(X)` and `q(Y)`.

Comment: "Rather Prolog will require q to finitely fail for every y" it's not like Prolog is magically supplying some values for Y before it tries out q(Y). it just tries to prove q(Y). if Y is free (not instantiated), some value will come about as part of the proof (or none will). the found substitution is then discarded (if any), and the success status is flipped. if q(Y) wasn't proved, p(X) is considered proved, with no substitution, i.e. X remains as it is. `\+ A` is non-logical: it means "couldn't prove A in the current state of the program". I'm not a logician though.

Comment: @false: why? Consider "everyone is happy if someone is rich", and "everyone is happy if somone isn't rich"

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, `p(X) :- \+ q(Y).` on its own doesn't sufficiently express the notion that *`p` holds true for every `X` if `q` fails for some `Y`* because Prolog doesn't know the possible universe of `Y` values that are eligible to test `q`. So, it doesn't know of any values of `Y`  for which `q(Y)` is not provable.

Let's suppose you had, though, the following:

```
q(a).
q(b).
q(c).

valid_y(Y) :- member(Y, [a,b,c,d,e]).
```

Then you could write:

```
p(_) :- valid_y(Y), \+ q(Y).
```

Then `p(_)` succeeds twice as Prolog seeks all solutions. You could use a cut or `once/1` to avoid that.